# ping: ddaw.com.rut: Name or service not known (docker)?

Tags: docker

Из запущенного контейнера если делаю ping до частного gitlab хоста,
пишет

```
> root@436436:/usr/src/app/src/temp# ping ddaw.com.rut
```

> ping: ddaw.com.rut: Name or service not known

А если с хоста, то пинг проходит успешно. 
Из-за чего это происходит?

ОС ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно прописать в /etc/hosts запись вида

> 122.12.10.191 ddaw.com.rut

Внутри dockerfile в момент сборки это можно сделать так:

```
echo "122.12.10.191 ddaw.com.rut" >> /etc/hosts
```

При запуске контейнера

```
-add-host="ddaw.com.rut:122.12.10.191"
```

Для docker-compose

```
extra_hosts:
 - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
 - "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
```

Comment: лучше было ресолверы настроить

Comment: А как это можно сделать и почему указанный подход хуже?